# Agregar Ventana Modal a Datatable

Tags: php, modal, datatable

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, y recientemente comencé a trabajar con DATATABLE agregándolo a una lista que tengo en mi sistema. El DATATABLE funciona sin problemas.
Lo que necesito y es por eso que solicito de su ayuda es agregar una ventana modal al presionar el botón de observaciones. Esta ventana modal me funcionaba correctamente cuando solo tenia una lista con PHP, pero ahora al agregar DATATABLE estoy un poco perdido. He buscado ejemplos en varios foros e incluso en la pagina de Datatable, pero sin resultados hasta ahora.
Esta ventana modal es para agregar observaciones a un registro de un alumno.

Les comparto mi código esperando que alguien por favor me pueda orientar.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Lists</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.0/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"> 
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>

     <div class="table-responsive-sm">
        <table id="mydatatable" style="width:100%">  
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Rut</th>
                    <th>Nombres</th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>Fecha Ingreso Práctica</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>   
                </tr>
            </thead>  
        </table>
    </div>



   ** CODIGO DATATABLE **

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
    listar();
   });
   var listar = function()
   {
    var table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable( 
    {
        ajax:
        {    
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            orderCellTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            responsive: true,
            ordering: true,
            url:'consultas/Lista.php',
            method:'POST'
        },

        columns:
        [
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"rut"},
            {"data":"nombres"},
            {"data":"apellidos"},
            {"data":"fecha_ingreso"},
            { "data": null,
                render: function(data){ 
                return "<a data-toggle="modal" data- 
                target="#id="+data['id']+"'>
                <button type ='button'><i class='fa fa-comment'></i></button></a>       

             <a href='editar.php?id="+data['id']+"'><button 
             type ='button'><i class='fa-pen-to-square'></i></button></a>" 
            }},  
        ],

        responsive: {
        details: {
        display: DataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
            header: function (row) {
                var data = row.data();
                return 'Details for ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1];
            }
        }),
        renderer: DataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
            tableClass: 'table'
        })
        }
      }

        language: {
        url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema principal es la definición de tu función `render()`, ten cuidado al definir los atributos correctamente ya que podrías estar declarandolos incorrectamente (revisar "data-target"), define de esta forma tu función `render()`

```
...
...
 columns:
        [
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"rut"},
            {"data":"nombres"},
            {"data":"apellidos"},
            {"data":"fecha_ingreso"},
            { "data": null,
                render: function(data){ 
                return "<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#id="+data['id']+"'>" +
                "<button type='button'><i class='fa fa-comment'></i></button></a>" +       
             "<a href='editar.php?id="+data['id']+"'><button type ='button'><i class='fa-pen-to-square'></i></button></a>" 
            }},  
        ]
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

En un proyecto donde tengo una lista de facturas, al final hay una celda de acciones, al dar click en la lupa, se despliega un modal con la factura. (Esta desarrollado sobre el framework Cakephp 2.10)

La forma de hacerlo fue la siguiente:

1. el código de render para la celda de acciones es:

```
{
                // target:14,
                "data": "Pago.id",
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        // definimos los botones como templates con el helper de cake para tener correctamente las url's
                        var _template = '<?php
                            echo '<div nowrap>';
                                echo '<span class="viewCard" on-click="displayInvoice()" data-id="__id__"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x" rel="tooltip"  data-placement="top" data-id="__id__" title="Ver Factura" style="color: #337ab7;"> </i></span> ';
                                // echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-search-plus fa-2x')), array('action' => 'view', '__id__'), array('escape' => false, 'title'=>__('View')));
                                echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-edit fa-2x')), array('action' => 'edit', '__id__') , array('escape' => false, 'title'=>__('Edit')));
                                echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-print fa-2x')), array('action' => 'view_pdf', 'ext' => 'pdf' , '__id__'),array('target'=>'_blank','escape' => false, 'title'=>__('Print')));

                                echo '<span class="sendEmail" data-id="__id__" ><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" rel="tooltip"  data-id="__id__" data-email="__email__" data-placement="top" title="Enviar eMail" style="color: #337ab7;"> </i></span> ';
                                echo $this->Form->postLink('<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" rel="tooltip"  data-id="__id__" data-email="__email__" data-placement="top" title="Anular factura" style="color: #337ab7;"> </i>',
                                        array('controller'=>'pagos', 'action' => 'anular','__id__',1),
                                        array('escape' => false), __('Esta seguro de anular la factura ?'));
                            echo '</div>';
                        ?>'
                        // esto ejecuta para cada fila generando los links correctamente reemplazando el id de cada item
                        return _template.replace(new RegExp('__id__', 'g'), data).replace(new RegExp('__email__', 'g'), full["Pago"]["email"]);
                }
            } ,
```

El llamado a mostrar el modal es on-click="displayInvoice()" en la linea

```
echo '<span class="viewCard" on-click="displayInvoice()" data-id="__id__"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x" rel="tooltip"  data-placement="top" data-id="__id__" title="Ver Factura" style="color: #337ab7;"> </i></span> ';
```

2. Crear un eventListener para todas las celdas que contengan la lupa para mostrar la factura (En efecto crea 2 uno para mostrar la factura y otro para enviar el email). Esto se logra con el método
   `drawCallback: function() {}`

```
pagosTable = $('#pagosTable').DataTable({
...
...
...
,
        drawCallback: function() {
            // Your function to fire after ajax.reload() goes here
            console.log('Table reloaded!');
            const viewCards = document.querySelectorAll('.viewCard');
            const sendEmails = document.querySelectorAll('.sendEmail');

            viewCards.forEach(viewCard => {
                viewCard.addEventListener('click', function displayEvent(event) {
                    console.log('viewCard clicked', event.target.dataset.id);
                    displayInvoice(event.target.dataset.id);
                });
            });

            sendEmails.forEach(sendEmail => {
                sendEmail.addEventListener('click', function sendEmailEvent(event) {
                    console.log('sendEmail clicked', event.target.dataset.id);
                    email = event.target.dataset.email;
                    id = event.target.dataset.id;
                    enviaEmail(email, id);
                });
            });

            // displayData();
            // generateCategoriesCard();


        },
```

3. Hacer un llamado ajax, para traer el resto de información de la factura  desplegarlo en un modal estandar

```
function displayInvoice(dataId) {
         // Accesses the data-id attribute
        console.log("Clicked element data-id:", dataId);
        url = '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("controller"=>"pagos","action"=>"get_view")); ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: url + '/' + dataId,

            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                // Parse the JSON response
                const paymentData = JSON.parse(response);
                // Generate the invoice card HTML
                const invoiceCard = generateInvoiceCard(paymentData);

                // Show the modal with the invoice card
                $('#invoice-card').html(invoiceCard);
                $('#pagoModal').modal('show');
                // Add event listener to close the card when clicked
                const closeButton = document.getElementById('view_close');
                closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log('Close button clicked');('Close button clicked');('Close button clicked');
                    // closeButton.parentElement.remove();
                    $('#pagoModal').modal('hide');
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
                alert('Error al obtener la información del pago');
            }
        });
    };
```

Espero te sirva.